# Add tests for django filters

Tags: python, django, testing, django-filter, factory-boy

I'm using factory-boy to add tests in Django, and I have a filter:

```
class filter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = modelname
        fields = ["name", "id", "price"]
```

I want to add tests for this filter. How should I write the test for it?